Decryption using randomness
There exist public-key encryption (PKE) schemes where any well-formed ciphertext can be decrypted if the random coins used during encryption are known. For instance, in ElGamal encryption, the public key is $pk = (G, q, g, h = g^x)$ and the secret key is $x$. To encrypt a message $m \in G$, one selects a random $y \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ and produces the ciphertext $(c_0 = g^y, c_1 = m \cdot h^y)$. Here, the random value $y$ is the only randomness used, and knowing $y$ allows one to easily recover $m$.
Such schemes are used in the literature. For example, Koppula and Waters (see page 3) starts with a CPA-secure scheme that has this extraction property and uses it to construct a CCA-secure PKE scheme.
My question is: Are there provably CPA-secure PKE schemes that do not have such extraction property?

RSA with OAEP padding?

You can compose a trapdoor one-way permutation (TDP) with PKE to obtain a new PKE without this extraction property.
Consider
$$\textsf{Enc}^*\Bigl( (PK_1, PK_2), M \Bigr) = \textsf{Enc}\bigl( PK_2, F( PK_1, M) \bigr),$$
where $\textsf{Enc}$ is a standard PKE and $F$ is a TDP. It's not hard to see that $\textsf{Enc}^*$ inherits CPA security from $\textsf{Enc}$.
Suppose for sake of contradiction that there is a way to extract from $\textsf{Enc}^*$:
$$\textsf{Extract}\Bigl( \textsf{Enc}^*\bigl( (PK_1,PK_2), M; R \bigr), R \Bigr) \leadsto M$$
Then I could use that extractor to break the security of the TDP, as follows:
Given $Y = F(PK_1, X)$ for an unknown, random $X$, I compute
$$ C = \textsf{Enc}(PK_2, \underline{Y}; R)$$
and give $(C,R)$ to the extractor. Since $C$ is a correct encryption (under $\textsf{Enc}^*$) of $X$ with randomness $R$, the extractor is bound to output $X$. Thus I have inverted the TDP.

Thank you for your answer. Also, I really enjoyed reading your textbook.
